# Android:Android SDK and AVD Manager doesn't launch after did SDK upgrade?

Tags: android

I have Android development eclipse setup on Mac OS X. I recently did Android SDK upgrade from 1.5 to available versions such as 1.6, 2.0.1 and 2.1 and docs. After did upgrade, automatically restarted my Macbook and installed all new versions. After this, when i try to launch "Windows->Android SDK and AVD Manager", it doesn't launch at all. What might be the reason? Does anyone has the solution?
The reason why i'm trying to launch Android SDK and AVD Manager is, i need to add new Android virtual device(avd) target for 2.0.1 and 2.1 versions, for that i'm trying to launch Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the latest version of the Android SDK AVD Manager requires that there be a few directories (empty) before the AVD Manager will launch.
In the SDK install directory, there must be sibling directories to tools for "platforms" and "add-ons".
Create those directories, restart Eclipse, then launch AVD Manager.
And that should do it.
Then You can Update All and get platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is actually caused by the fact that android is installed on `c:\program files` folder (the commands executed by android consider that the called folder is `c:\program` which is a non existent folder and this issue is due to the space in the name of this folder).

So the solution is to reinstall your program under a folder with non spaced name (for example `c:\Android`) and it should be fine.

Note: this problem can also be related to a problem of jre problem so make sure you have the appropriate version for android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching Eclipse with the -clean option?

The clean option clears any cached data Eclipse might be using, so it may resolve the SDK/AVD Manager issue you are encountering.

Here is a more in-depth explanation:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Here is one example of launching Eclipse from a command line (Terminal) in OSX with the -clean option:

http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/06/30/run-eclipse-from-the-command-line-on-os-x/

Comment: Hi, I didn't get you clearly. How do we do that? I use Eclipse development on Mac OS X. How do i launch Eclipse with clean option?

Comment: I've added some more info in the answer above

Comment: Thanks. I tried ./eclipse -clean -vmargs -XstartOnFirstThread to launch eclipse clean, and then tried launching "Windows->Android SDK and AVD Manager", but the same issue, it doesn't launch.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update your "SDK tools" as well as downloading the Android v2.1 SDK itself. I had the problem where after downloading v2.1, suddenly nothing worked as I got the message I needed to update to SDK tools rev5 - that update doens't happen automatically when you go to the AVD manager and download the "available packages". I don't know if it's the same on a Mac, but on the PC it was as simple as going to "Help -> Check for Updates" in Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the reply. When i do Check for updates, it shows me only Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.2.2.x version, not anything related to SDK tools rev5. It didn't ask me to install SDK tools rev5 from anywhere.

Comment: The tools where a separate download to the eclipse plugin for me, perhaps download the latest version user187532.

Comment: Ok then you might have to update them manually. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing - in particular, about a third of the way down the page it gives you the detailed instructions on how to download and install the new plugin. But I recommend reading the whole page, just to make sure you don't miss something.

Comment: Oh, totally being confused whenever i see android developer installation site i am totally crapping up all over again, such a confusing part explained here and there we need to install/update so many things...oh, i'm just quitting from it. 
As steve said, i tried installing plugin again by following topics "Downloading the ADT Plugin" (or) "Configuring the ADT Plugin" (or) "Troubleshooting ADT Installation" in the same site. Nothing has worked out, it says all the softwares already installed.

Answer (score 0):

the newer version of the SDK tools is probably in a different folder than the old version, so update

Window -> Preferences -> SDK Location.

Paul

Check the install is ok by running the commands from the tools directory manually to check it's not an issue with the install

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and traced it to a faulty swt.jar file in the folder

> [adroid_sdk]\tools\lib[platform]

Downloaded a new one from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ and put all the files into the above directory. For me [platform] was "x86", but it might be different for you, though I only had 3 folders to choose from and I dont think it will hurt if you put the files in all of them.